# Using Disqus with entity translation

Tags: i18n-l10n, comments

We're rebuilding our bilingual site on Drupal 7 and would like to use entity translation since it seems that will make later migration more reasonable. We've also been using Disqus for commenting for years now, and it works really well for moderation and not having to deal with the potentially huge amounts of data should spam start flowing in--I used Drupal comments and Mollom with bad results years ago.

The question is, how can we have a Disqus or similar third-party commenting thread on each version of a translated post in their own language without separate node IDs? Has anyone cracked this yet?

**UPDATE:** We may have come across a solution, but I'd welcome others' thoughts. The Disqus multi-lingual website page describes using the `this.language` JS variable to dynamically load the Disqus embed in a different language on per page basis.

```
var disqus_config = function () {
this.language = "ru";
};
```

The solution would be to use javascript to change that variable depending on the language selected for the page. So on load `this.language = "en"`, then I select Spanish and it changes `this.language = "es"`.

This seems like a pretty solid solution. Anyone see an issue?

Comment: To be clear, should each different language have a unique set of comments? If you don't mind mixing languages, it should be possible using language configuration: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466249-multi-lingual-websites

Comment: The regional offices (including EU) do think it's important to not combine languages. I've also read elsewhere that it generally degrades the quality of discussion.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this in Drupal (thus it's not an answer), but I'd look at seeing if you can namespace the `disqus_identifier` with the language (it normally looks like `node/1234`). So in combination with the `this.language` variable, you can have unique discussions in each language.